# Post Request throwing 401 http status code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to set webelement  variable which dynamically generated when a project is created and then passing the variable on to my POST request.

```
WebElement projectId  = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
String projectIdValue = projectId.getText();
System.out.println(projectIdValue);
Thread.sleep(3000);          
RestAssured.baseURI= "https://abc.co.uk";
String response= given().header("Content-Type","application/json").body("payload.test1").when().post(projectIdValue).then().assertThat().statusCode(200).toString();
```

with the above code when executed i am getting HTTP 401 status code. But when i manually set the  value like below then my request is throwing http 200 as expected.

```
String  response= given().header("Content-Type","application/json").body("payload.test1").when().post("4d0dfa9d260d46c99ade992e850201fa").then().assertThat().statusCode(200).toString();
```

How to fix this issue? In run time i need to dynamically locate the webElement and use that in my HTTP request using selenium

Comment: could you log the value of "projectIdValue" and see what value is set?

Comment: What is console logged here? System.out.println(projectIdValue);

Comment: It’s printing the correct webelement

Comment: It needs to return "4d0dfa9d260d46c99ade992e850201fa".

Comment: Yes it is returning ‘ 4d0dfa9d260d46c99ade992e850201fa’